# Getting error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" in Heroku while accessing HTML page with Node.JS

Tags: html, node.js, express, heroku

I have deployed `index.html`page with the help of `Node.JS` in `Heroku` . This is the file structure i am following in Heroku

```
-- Index.js
 -- public
     -- css
          -- index.css
     -- JS
          -- index.js
     -- index.html
     -- home.html
 -- procfile
 -- package.json
```

In server script `index.js`

```
//express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const path = require('path')


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Current directory:", __dirname);
    console.log("filename: ", __filename);
  
    //serve the html page
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
  });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
  });
```

After deploy the code and run the server.js file , i am getting below error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'
```

I don't understand why this error coming. I have the `index.html` file in the `public` folder.

So in order to understand the path of the heroku i have added below lines in the `server.js` file

```
console.log("Current directory:", __dirname); // return the path
console.log("filename: ", __filename); // return the index.js file path
```

and the corresponding output as follows:

```
Current directory: /app
filename:  /app/index.js
```

Now `/app` is the main directory of the application. So then why `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));` is returning the `error no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'`?

Also i have tried `express.static` method in `server.js` like

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html');
 });
```

then i got new error

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

After that i have tried one more method

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Then i got same error  `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'`

Any suggestion? How to access `index.html` and `home.html` Anything i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
```

Comment: getting sam error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'`